# How to use libraries ".lib" and ".a" files in GCC

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

I have simple C code that uses some functions of `libavcodec` in [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg). I try to compile the code with GCC (on Windows using [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)) as follows:

```
gcc -o mycode mycode.c
```

But I get a lot of errors like "undefined reference to av_free". I know that these functions are defined in the libraries of FFmpeg. I do access files like `avcodec.lib` and `libavcodec.dll.a`, but I don't know how to use them with GCC so that I can compile and make my file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is this on Windows only ? If so, please precise which GCC distribution you are using (mingw, cygwin...)

Comment: @SirDarius : yes I am using mingw. I mentioned this in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
gcc -o mycode mycode.c -L C:\path\to\avcodec -lavcodec
```

I don't have Windows, so I cannot test it myself.

The point is that you need to tell gcc that some functions are in avcodec.lib / .dll. After the `-L` you tell where the .a / .dll is, then you must tell the linker to actually consider the avcodec.lib / .dll, that corresponds to `-lavcodec`.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I tried what you suggested, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @BlueSky Most likely you need to link other libraries as well, not just the avcodec.lib.

Comment: I believe av_free is in libavutil, so add `-lavutil`

Comment: @BlueSky As szatmary says, please try adding `-lavutil`.